# How to write this graph related algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm, graph

So let's say you have a train and 10.000 (0...9999) stations. The train is at the station number 0.

Every station has some cargo to be delivered to the one of any other stations. And the amount of cargo to be delivered to other station is random: 1 ~ 100 tons per station.

Your train can carry only up to 50 tons at once. Once train picked cargo on any station, it must unload it before it can pick up next cargo (i.e. if at current time train is carrying 1 ton, it can't pick up more cargo even though it has space for 49 tons left).

So develop the algorithm the train will deliver all cargo in shortest time.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vehicle_routing_problem).

Comment: You might have better luck with this type of question over at [Comp Sci stack exchange](http://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What should the algorithm do? I assume you want to find the optimal path, but you should explicitly mention it. Finding a non-optimal path is an easy task, I think you can also get 2-approximation with greedy (intuition only, not proof).

Comment: @Krishna Is this a programming challenge? Also, by "shortest time" do you mean "least number of stops"?

Comment: @SaviourSelf...This is a problem scenario asked in Google interview..

Answer (score 0):

This is my first pass quickly thinking about this question, and if I think of a better response I'll come back and edit my answer. Someone else may be able to take what I provide and help you out more too. This is the "brute force" approach, and there may be a better way of solving this.

1. Enumerate all origin/destination pairs (which looks to be an input.) -10,000 operations. 
   For stations requiring more capacity than the train can provide, split these into additional origin/destination pairs.
2. Enumeration all permutations of origin/destination pairs - 10,000! operations (n*n complexity) - inside a loop, not saving each
   one.
3. For each permutation, calculate the total distance the train drives. For each pair, this will be the previous distance driven
   plus the train to origin + the train to the destination. Do this for all the pairs in the permutation. Compare
   this single value to the single value of you have from before.
   If it is smaller, keep this one and the string of permutations.
   Throw away your previous string of permutations if you keep a new one. This should be
   10,000 * c (1?) operations. Only save one of these permutations, if
   you save all of them you will run out of memory if you do. I think.

I think the complexity of this is going to be AROUND n+n*n+n = 2n+n^2. This should be doable for 10,000 stations. Be careful with the memory, when I initially started writing this, I thought of saving all permutations which would have taken like 20,000! in memory.

Sorry I'm using the U.S. way of , instead of . for a place separator of thousands.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=10000%21) and click [More digits] a few time. 10000! ~ 2.84 * 10^35659, and NOT n*n.